# morris.js chart doesn't work on production server

Tags: javascript, raphael, morris.js, dev-to-production

I have this `morris.js` chart which I populated with random values (the ones provided in the exemple). Whereas it renders perfectly in `localhost`, once I upload on the production server it no longer works.

### Set up

**JS code**

```
new Morris.Line({
        element: 'daily-chart',
        data: [
            { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
            { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
            { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
            { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
            { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
        ],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id="daily-chart" style="height: 350px; width: 1000px">

</div>
```

### Rendering

**In Chrome/Opera**

Despite the `width` and `height` set up in the `#daily-chart` `<div>`, the dimensions are not set up properly. I only see one part of the chart, the rest being hidden. It's about 50px width despite of `<div id="daily-chart" style="height: 350px; width: 1000px">`.

**In Firefox**

The script gets busy or does not respond at all. I get the following message : `A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.` with `Continue|Stop script` choices and the browser freezes. It states that the line is the `1164` which is a while condition :

```
while ((t = d.getTime()) <= dmax) { // <-- 1164 line
  if (t >= dmin) {
    ret.push([spec.fmt(d), t]);
  }
  spec.incr(d);
}
```

No errors in console or whatsoever except when I stop the script where I get :

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
Morris.labelSeries@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:1164:1
Morris.Line</Line.prototype.drawXAxis@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:930:11
Morris.Line</Line.prototype.draw@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:890:9
Morris.Grid</Grid.prototype.redraw@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:472:9
Morris.Grid</Grid.prototype.setData@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:338:9
Grid@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:102:7
Line@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:726:7
Line@https://<url>/js/uncompressed/morris.js:724:9
@https://<url>/<path/to/webpage>:1171:9
```

### Other specs

The production server uses an HTTPS protocol and PHP version (don't think this is related at all) is `5.4.29` on dev and `5.4.30` on prod. As far as I know, these are the only differences.

---

What is causing the issue?

Comment: Did you try to put that in a plain HTML file (no php) to see if the problem was still there? The only role for the server in this case is to serve the files. If there is nothing wrong in the "Network" tab of your console, it might be aliens messing around.

Comment: As per your recommendation, I've set up a `morris.js` chart in a plain HTML file and it works on the production server. I'm investigating why it doesn't when included in my app...

Comment: Ok, then your problem is with PHP, maybe you could check if there is any difference between the HTML code you get served on the production and development servers.

Comment: How come PHP would interfer with `morris.js` javascript file?

Comment: Well, that might be the case if you output something with PHP... Hard to tell

Comment: It works! I've moved the calls to `raphael.js` and `morris.js` javascript files to `Bootstrap.php` (I'm using ZF1.12) where I load all the JS files for all files and it works. Can't figure out why though... many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still trying to figure out a solution , do make sure you check all the stylesheets that have been linked as well as the link of the jquery plugins.

For example :

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.0/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

Should be replaced with

```
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.0/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

and so on.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow: Is it solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Script isn't answering any more error using morris.js in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061821/script-isnt-answering-any-more-error-using-morris-js-in-firefox)

Just add the attribute

```
parseTime: false
```

to your Morris chart at creation time.