# Morris Chart - Raphael JS Crashes Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, raphael, morris.js

This is the story:
I have a DOM of my main web page like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="dashboard_graph">
</div>
```

The above DOM is used for showing dashboard page by default.
I use `div#dashboard_graph`elemen for showing the area chart. I make an ajax call to get the chart values, and build the chart when the data is sucessfully received. This is the function:

```
   function build_dashboardchart(){
        $.ajax({
            url     : "<?php echo site_url();?>/monitoring/get_data",
            data    : "for=dashboard",
            type    : "post",
            dataType: "json",
            cache   : false,
            success : function (data){
                Morris.Area({
                    element: 'dashboard_graph',
                    behaveLikeLine : true,
                    data: data.data,
                    xkey: 'time',
                    ykeys: data.ykeys,
                    labels: data.labels,
                    resize: true,
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    lineColors: ['#ED5D5D','#32D2C9', '#D6D23A' ],
                    pointSize: 0,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    postUnits:" kWh",
                    hideHover : 'auto'
                });
                build_updowntime();
            },
            error   : function (a){
                alert(a.responseText+"|"+a.statusText);
            }
        });
```

The area chart successfully generated. I don't face any problem here.

I am using `div.wrapper` element for showing the web contents (not only dashboard page). And then, I  load another page into `div.wrapper` element by using ajax call. It means, the dashboard page (which includes the chart) will be replaced by new page.

```
        function opencontent(ini){
            var type        = $(ini).attr("data-type");
            var page        = $(ini).attr("data-page");
            $.ajax({
                url     : "<?php echo site_url();?>/main/load_page/",
                data    : "type="+type+"&page="+page,
                type    : "post",
                dataType: "html",
                success : function (data){
                    $("div.wrapper").empty();
                    $("div.wrapper").html(data);
                },
                error   : function (a){
                    alert(a.responseText+"|"+a.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
```

The new page successfully replaced the dashboard page. But, I have my browser hanging for 10 - 20 seconds. And I get a prompt to debug, stop, or continuing the script. It says the browser has a problem with raphael.js at several lines.

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
paths@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/raphael.js:1012:1
R.pathBBox@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/raphael.js:1298:19
elproto.getBBox@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/raphael.js:2623:28
R._extractTransform@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/raphael.js:1910:40
elproto.transform@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/raphael.js:4451:9
b.Line</c.prototype.drawXAxis/a@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:16621
b.Line</c.prototype.drawXAxis@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:17449
b.Line</c.prototype.draw@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:16300
b.Grid</d.prototype.redraw@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:8260
b.Grid</d.prototype.resizeHandler@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:10982
f/<@http://localhost/~okierie/tismidea/public/main/js/morris-chart/morris.js:6:77
```

I don't have any javascript included or executed in the web pages I loaded into `div.wrapper` element. So, how could I 'mess arround' raphel.js and morris? Is there a method to safely clear the chart (without disturbing raphaeljs)?

Comment: In your `opencontent` function, you're emptying your div `wrapper`. So your div `dashboard_graph` will no longer exist if you want to add a Morris Chart.

Comment: @krlzlx yes,  i clear the chart, and replace it by new page. my problem is : raphael js was being crazy/freezing the browser after i replace the chart. I don't want it happen.

Comment: Did you look at this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550627/morris-js-chart-doesnt-work-on-production-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550627/morris-js-chart-doesnt-work-on-production-server) ?

Comment: I did, and I voted +1 for that question, no answer. The comments are not clear enough to fix this thing @krlzlx.